# Can't install github desktop

Tags: github, windows-10

I get this error msg.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1637.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                        Server      : AmazonS3
    Application url         : https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_3_3_4_0/GitHub.exe.manifest
                        Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=3.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : GitHub.exe, Version=3.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The application binding data format is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B2)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [3/19/2017 7:14:58 PM] : Activation of https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
    * [3/19/2017 7:14:59 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [3/19/2017 7:14:59 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [3/19/2017 7:15:00 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [3/19/2017 7:15:08 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [3/19/2017 7:15:08 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [3/19/2017 7:19:30 PM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [3/19/2017 7:19:30 PM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [3/19/2017 7:19:30 PM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - The application binding data format is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B2)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IEnumSTORE_ASSEMBLY.Next(UInt32 celt, STORE_ASSEMBLY[] rgelt)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreAssemblyEnumeration.MoveNext()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.CollectCrossGroupApplications(Uri codebaseUri, DefinitionIdentity deploymentIdentity, Boolean& identityGroupFound, Boolean& locationGroupFound, String& identityGroupProductName)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: You may want to contact GitHub support for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear everything out of the Apps folder:

- Remove the 2.0 folder from **%LocalAppData%\Apps**

Also, turn off your firewall for private and public profile and then retry.

You can look at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/637f2923-91a4-400c-830e-2d92c4e908ed/the-application-binding-data-format-is-invalid?forum=winformssetup) for more detail.